# Getting error Unknown command: `server' on git cvsimport

Tags: git, cvs

I followed [git-cvsimport](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport) documentation to port my legacy code to from CVS to git. Installed cvsps version 2.1 and added to path.

Ran `git cvsimport -C <destination_folder> <project_folder_with_cvs>`

Getting an error:

```
Unknown command: `server'

CVS commands are:
    add          Add a new file/directory to the repository
    admin        Administration front end for rcs
.
.
(Specify the --help option for a list of other help options)
Failed to read from server at D:\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-cvsimport line 420.
```

I am working in windows 10.
Any clue why this error is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [reported here](http://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/UL95azl0/git-cvsimport-fails-noisily-if-cvs-has-no-server-support)

> `git-cvsimport` now exits less noisily and prints an appropriate
>   message when the installed cvs binary doesn't know the '`server`'
>   subcommand; this happens when `cvs` is `./configure`'ed with
>   `--disable-server`.

[This ticket](http://customer.march-hare.com/webtools/bugzilla/ttshow_bug.cgi?tt=1&id=5940) mentions:

> The '`server`' command has been replaced with the '`preload`' command.

All that is consistent with the [`git-cvsimport` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport):

> `git cvsimport` uses **cvsps version 2**, which is considered deprecated; **it does not work with cvsps version 3 and later**.
>   If you are performing a one-shot import of a CVS repository consider using [`cvs2git`](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html) or [`cvs-fast-export`](http://www.catb.org/esr/cvs-fast-export/).

Try those latest tools instead.

Comment: Thank you VonC, so `git cvsimport` will not work at all? In that case I shall try cvs2git